# autocomplete search multiple parts of string, then returns the most likely ones

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

[Kind of like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824144/how-do-i-use-jquery-autocomplete-for-multiple-words)

I have many text snippets that I use many, many, many times a day.  I want to build something that can search a database/ preferably a javascript array full of sentence length strings, returning the most likely one.  Most autocomplete returns things you type in the sequence you type them.  I do not remember seeing what I describe.

For example; Say I have this item in my array:
"a yellow banana"

When I search for "a banana" it won't show me anything. 
It only works when I typ "a yello" ... etc.

Is it possible to also return matches when multiple words are present in an item's name, but on different places?

So when I typ, for example, "**fox quick dog**" that it returns:

"The **quick** brown **fox** jumps over the lazy **dog**"

[got the idea and question from actb.js](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jsactb.aspx)

Thanks for helping me be more lazy

Comment: It doesn't need to be javascript... if microsoft came out with this in their 2003 Access release or something, i don't care.  Just something that can be utilized on a normal office pc xp sp2 setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help: **[jQuery Quick Search](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/quicksearch/)**

Comment: That is it.  Thank you.  The list search example does it exactly as I need it too.

Comment: @ichiban the link doesn't exist anymore. Can I get a redirect?